# Why sometimes in the output of the producer-consumer problem, the consumer is getting a previous value instead of the new value produced by producer?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, producer-consumer, thread-synchronization

I have this below Java code:

```java
class Q2 {
    int n;
    boolean valueSet = false;

    synchronized int get() {
        while(!valueSet)
            try {
                System.out.println("Consumer waiting ...");
                wait();
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e) {
                System.err.println("InterruptedException caught");
            }
        System.out.println("Consumer awakened");
        System.out.println("Got: "+n);
        valueSet = false;
        notify();
        System.out.println("Consumer called notify()");
        return n;
    }

    synchronized void put(int n) {
        while(valueSet)
            try {
                System.out.println("Producer waiting ...");
                wait();
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e) {
                System.err.println("InterruptedException caught");
            }
        System.out.println("Producer awakened");
        System.out.println("Before put n is: " + this.n);
        this.n = n;
        valueSet = true;
        System.out.println("Put: " + this.n);
        notify();
        System.out.println("Producer called notify()");
    }
}

class Producer2 implements Runnable {
    Q2 q;
    int noOfTimes;

    Producer2(Q2 q) {
        this.q = q;
        new Thread(this, "Producer").start();
    }

    public void run() {
        int i=0;
        noOfTimes=0;
        while(q.n < 2) {
            q.put(i++);
            noOfTimes++;
        }
        System.out.println("Producer ran: " + noOfTimes + " times.");
    }
}

class Consumer2 implements Runnable {
    Q2 q;
    int noOfTimes;

    Consumer2(Q2 q) {
        this.q = q;
        new Thread(this, "Consumer").start();
    }

    public void run() {
        int i=0;
        noOfTimes=0;
        while(q.n < 2) {
            System.out.println("Iteration " + (noOfTimes+1) + "; Before get() n is: " + q.n);
            int val = q.get();
            System.out.println("After get() n is: " + q.n);
            noOfTimes++;
        }
        System.out.println("Consumer ran: " + noOfTimes + " times.");
        System.out.println("n: " + q.n);
    }
}

public class PCFixed {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Q2 q = new Q2();
        new Producer2(q);
        new Consumer2(q); 
    }
}
```

One particular output:

```
Producer awakened
Before put n is: 0 // because n is int and default value of n is 0
Put: 0 // instance variable n associated with object of Q2 is set to 0
Producer called notify() // no effect
Producer waiting ... // thread spawned from Producer waits
Iteration 1; Before get() n is: 0 // context switching to thread spawned from Consumer
Consumer awakened
Got: 0
Consumer called notify()
After get() n is: 0
Iteration 2; Before get() n is: 0
Producer awakened // context switching to Producer's thread
Before put n is: 0
Put: 1
Producer called notify()
Producer waiting ... // Producer's thread waits/sleeps
Consumer awakened // context switching to Consumer's thread
Got: 1
Consumer called notify()
After get() n is: 1
Producer awakened // context switching to Producer's thread
Before put n is: 1
Put: 2 // #### line 1
Producer called notify()
Iteration 3; Before get() n is: 1 // #### line 2: context switching to Consumer's thread
Producer ran: 3 times. // context switching to Producer's thread
Consumer awakened // context switching to Consumer's thread
Got: 2
Consumer called notify()
After get() n is: 2
Consumer ran: 3 times.
n: 2 // Consumer's thread ends here
```

Can someone help me understand why, in the above output, at line 2 the value of `n` fetched by consumer is 1 when the producer already produced a new value which is 2 at line 1? Since the same instance of `Q2` are being shared by both the Producer's and Consumer's thread why is the changed value of `n` not being reflected at line 2? Also please clarify me the meaning of a threaded object even though I know what a thread is?

And if you don't see this behavior on running once the above code run a few times and you will see such behavior.

Comment: ++i instead of i++

Comment: @Anon I don't get what you are referring to.

Comment: on Producer2 class in the run method change the i++ to ++i

Comment: @Anon I don't understand how changing i++ to ++i will solve this problem. I am asking why the changed value of n is not being reflected in another thread.

Comment: if you used the debug you would notice that it only changes after so change the i++ to ++i and start using the debug

Answer (score 0):

Your read from `q.n` in `Consumer2::run` is racy, i.e. it is executed concurrently with the write to `q.n` in `Q2::put`. As a result, it can read either the previous value or the currently written value of `q.n`. A possible solution is move the printing of "Before get() n is ..." to under the lock.